# Blocking a certain user from apearing in user search results

Tags: 7, users, search

I'm looking for a way to exclude certain users (by ID or name) from appearing in the user search results in Drupal 7.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using drupal search out of the box to search users, that should still call implementations of [hook_search_page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.api.php/function/hook_search_page/7)

Build a small custom module that implements hook_search_page, parse thru `$results` and remove anything you don't want appearing in search results.

```
function custom_module_search_page($results) {
  foreach($results as $result_index => $result) { 
    //do something, maybe detect for a user id
    //and run unset($results[$result_index]); if the criteria is met
  }
}
```